# Insert new row for binary systems with SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql, oracle11g

I have the following table

```
 (cl1  ,  cl2)
  ----  ----
  (a   ,  1)
  (a   ,  2)
  (b   ,  2)
  (c   ,  1)
  (c   ,  2)
```

each a , b ,c  can take two values (1 or 2 or both).

My question is :
How to insert a new row (with 0 on cl2) for all the cl1 that have only 1 or 2 and NOT the both in the example. I would like to insert the following row :

```
----
(b   ,  0)
----
```

Comment: What database is this? MySQL or Oracle? You have conflicting tags.

Comment: Could you please provide a little more information about your problem? What database are you using? Do you have any code yet? if so, can you provide it? Is there an error message?

Comment: Thank you, it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the BD is Oracle. Hope the below snippet helps.

```
SELECT B.CL1,
  0
FROM
  (SELECT A.CL1,
    CASE
      WHEN WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(A.CL2) LIKE '%1%'
      AND WMSYS.WM_CONCAT(A.CL2) LIKE '%2%'
      THEN 'both'
      ELSE 'one'
    END rnk
  FROM
    (SELECT 'a' cl1,1 cl2 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'a' cl1,2 cl2 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'b' cl1,2 cl2 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c' cl1,1 cl2 FROM dual
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'c' cl1,2 cl2 FROM dual
    )A
  GROUP BY A.CL1
  )B
WHERE B.rnk = 'one';
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are better ways, but here is one way to do it using `group by` and a `having` clause to enforce your rules (I'm assuming Oracle syntax):

```
insert into tbl (cl1, cl2)
(select cl1, 0
   from tbl
  group by cl1
 having count(case when cl2 in (1, 2) then 'X' end) != 0 -- contains 1 or 2
    and (count(case when cl2 = 1 then 'X' end) = 0 -- but not both
         or count(case when cl2 = 2 then 'X' end) = 0)
)
```

**EDIT**

A much simpler way:

```
insert into tbl (cl1, cl2)
(select cl1, 0
   from tbl
  where cl2 in (1, 2)
  group by cl1
 having count(distinct cl2) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable (cl1 VARCHAR(2), cl2 INT);

INSERT INTO TestTable (cl1, cl2) VALUES ('a', 1), ('a', 2), ('b', 1), ('c', 1), ('c', 2);

INSERT INTO TestTable (cl1, cl2)
SELECT cl1, 0
FROM TestTable 
WHERE cl1 NOT IN (
    SELECT cl1
    FROM TestTable 
    WHERE cl2 IN (1, 2)  
    GROUP BY cl1
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cl2) = 2
);
```

MySQL Demo: http://rextester.com/XWHGF50183

---

The below block returns the `cl1` those have the `cl2` is 1 and 2. Based on the result using NOT IN you can achieve the result.

```
SELECT cl1
FROM TestTable 
WHERE cl2 IN (1, 2)  
GROUP BY cl1
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cl2) = 2
```

Help from this [answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/97935/68079)

Comment: The problem is that your *below block* returns rows that have `1` ***or*** `2`, not `1` ***and*** `2`.  So your outer query's `not in` clause will filter out all valid rows as well.

Comment: @sstan That was a copy/paste issue. Please find the [fiddle](http://rextester.com/XWHGF50183)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
insert into [YOUR TABLE NAME] 
      select cl1,0 from [YOUR TABLE NAME] 
    group by cl1 having count(distinct cl2)<> 2
;
```